How to use tailwind animation in react-native with classname?
i try to animate some component like view or button by using Tailwind in my expo react-native project by no success in addition into website doc i noticed that it support animation and transition
Robust Animations - Full support for Tailwind's animation classes and custom keyframe animations via react-native-reanimated
 Transitions - Smooth transitions between style states, including dark mode changes and dynamic updates
https://www.nativewind.dev/
 <Button title='press' className="transition ease-in-out delay-150 bg-blue-500 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 hover:bg-indigo-500 duration-300 ..."/>



make sure you installed the needed the needed dependencies:
npm install nativewind react-native-reanimated
if you're using expo:
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-tailwindcss-react-native

config your babel.config.js, your babel.config.js should look like this:




module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      ["babel-preset-expo", { jsxImportSource: "nativewind" }],
      "nativewind/babel",
    ],
    plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin",'babel-plugin-dotenv'],
  };
};




now you also need to config tailwind.config.js for the project,
if you dont have it then:
 npx tailwindcss init
then change the content to this:




/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
...
}




import this in your root _layout : import 'react-native-reanimated';

now after making sure you've configured everything right this is an example of how you define your own Animations in the tailwind.config.js:




module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        'fade-in': 'fadeIn 1s ease-in-out',
      },
      keyframes: {
        fadeIn: {
          '0%': { opacity: 0 },
          '100%': { opacity: 1 },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};



then use it like this:


<View className="animate-fade-in">
  <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
</View>




myconfig is bebel like module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);
return {
presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
plugins: ["nativewind/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
};
};

tailwaind config is:/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} /
module.exports = {
// NOTE: Update this to include the paths to all of your component files.
content: ["./app*/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./index.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
theme: {
extend: {
animation: {
"fade-in": "fadeIn 1s ease-in-out",
},
keyframes: {
fadeIn: {
"0%": { opacity: 0 },
"100%": { opacity: 1 },
},
},
},
},
plugins: [],
};

but no fade animation appear ! in hello world
